# Appending text from first line to last of a file through loop

Tags: bash, shell

I want to append a text to the end of the each line of a existing file. This text has to be appended from the first line of the file to last line.

The thing is, I am passing the file contents as an input to the loop and output of that has to be appended onto the same file. I could not figure out a logic for it.

FileName: sample

```
cat sample
Alex, Johston
Samuel, John
Vebron, Justus
```

Above are the content of the file. Now, in this, I want to append first column of values ie) Alex, Samuel and Verbron to the end of the file with comma.

My intented output:

```
Alex, Johston,Alex
Samuel, John,Samuel
Vebron, Justus,Vebron
```

My script I wrote to take the first column values:

```
while
read LINE
do
fcol=$(echo $LINE|awk -F, '{ print $1 }')
done < sample
```

Running through the above loop, variable `fcol` will store the values - Alex, Samuel, Vebron. I need to append these values into end of each line

Can some one guide me on this and so that I can alter the above code to have the intented output as explained above.

Thanks!

Comment: @Rehman Basha and @nu11p01n73R: yes, it can be done through that. But, I want to take in the logic I want. Ok I will provide a another sample:                                                     `while
    read LINE
    do
    fcol=$(echo $LINE|awk -F, '{ print $1 }')
    wget -o wgetlog --output-document=genderinfo.html "http://gendersay.com/username=$fcol"
    gender=$(grep -o --perl-regexp "(?<=genderinformation,value:gend_)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+" genderinfo.html
    done < sample`

Comment: Running through the above loop will fetch the gender information of `fcol` values - Alex, Samuel, Vebron. Now I need to append the values of `gender` into end of each line and also correspondingly. Appending process have to start from first line to last line

Comment: @Rehman Basha: Can you guys help me for the above?

Comment: Please check my new answer. Let me know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialize `line_no = 0` before looping through the file.

Increment `line_no` by 1 before processing each line:

Following sed command will append the `$fcol` at the end of the `$line_no`
`sed -i "$line_no s/$/ ,$fcol/" sample`

Final Script:

```
line_no=0

while read LINE
do  
line_no=$((line_no+1))
fcol=$(echo $LINE|awk -F, '{ print $1 }')
sed -i "$line_no s/$/ ,$fcol/" sample
done < sample
```

Comment: You just have to replace fcol with the gender I guess.. based on the sample you provided on the comments above.

Comment: I tried with the above code. All the `fcol` values gets appended to the first line itself. I got the output like this: `cat sample
Alex, Johston,Alex,Samuel,Vebron
Samuel, John
Vebron, Justus`

Comment: `line_no=$(($line_no+1))` has given me the solution. Anyway, Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

`awk -F, '{print $0", "$1}' sample`

The loop is not required as the awk takes each line from the input file and process it based on the command provided.

Here the command is `print $0", "$1` which appends the `$0` and `$1` with a `","` between them

Comment: `print $0,", "$1` (as in the explanation) will print `<orig line> , <first field>` as opposed to `print $0", "$1` (as in the first line) which will print `<orig line>, <first line>`. ... That's mostly just a really long way of saying the explanation has a typo.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without an intermediate file of some sort (without storing the files contents in memory before processing them). That said things like `sed -i` will hide that detail from you.

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{print $0,$1}' sample > sample.new

sed -i.orig -e 's/^\(.\)\(.*\)/&\1/' sample
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use awk to do this :

```
cat sample |awk -F "," '{print $0 ", "$1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is

```
sed -r 's/([^,]*).*/\0, \1/'
```